# express-formidable returns " undefined" when i console.log req.files.path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get the path for my uploaded picture to later assign it to a profile picture src.

the problem is when i try to get the path it returns " undefined "

Here's the code:

```
var formidable=require('express-formidable');
var express=require('express');

var app=express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 

app.use(formidable({
  uploadDir: 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/formidable/pics',
  multiples: true,
  keepExtensions : true,
  hash:false
}));

app.get('/',function(req, res) {  
  res.render('layout')
});

app.post('/upload',(req, res) => {
console.log(req.files.path);


});


app.listen(5000,console.log('Server is running'));
```

Would appreciate it if anyone could give me a hint on the problem.

Thx

[result of console.log(req.files);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nstdA.png)

Comment: What do you get when you use `console.log(req.files);` ?

Comment: i get an array of info containing all meta data of the uploaded image.like name,path,size etc. but it's strange when i want to access them it returns undefined.

Comment: There you go then. It's an array, check `req.files[0].path`.

Comment: Didn't work Ben ;).

Comment: it's actually json data to be more specific.

Comment: No image uploaded???

Comment: @DavidR the image uploads to the directory , but i cant retrieve its path with req.files.path , which theoretically should work fine. not only the path , every other property is undefined as well. but i can see all data when i just console.log(req.files)

Comment: Can you please update this post with a screenshot of what you get when you do `console.log(req.files);` ?

Comment: just did bro @DavidR

Comment: @C.Amirani, try, `req.files.picture.path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `console.log(req.files)` statement, you have a file inside the `picture key`. So you need to use,

`req.files.picture.path`

```
 app.post('/upload',(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files.picture.path);
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

Comment: Glad to help you. :)